# Load Selector/Load Switch

Tags: switches, load, pmos, analog-switch

Following the provided schematic, my goal is to design a circuit that can determine the direction of a Pulse signal based on a control signal (CTL). To achieve this, I am utilizing two pmos transistors, each connected to a load at their drains. The objective is to redirect the Pulse signal to either the normally open (NO_LOAD) or normally closed (NC_LOAD) load, depending on the voltage level of CTL.

Specifically, when CTL is at 0 volts, the Pulse signal should be directed to NO_LOAD (with NC_LOAD set to 0 volts). Conversely, when CTL is at 5 volts, the Pulse signal should be directed to NC_LOAD (with NO_LOAD set to 0 volts).

However, during simulation, I am encountering an issue where the Pulse signal is simultaneously present at both the BUFFER and NOT nodes. This is unexpected, and upon investigation, it appears that the PMOS transistors are inadvertently reinjecting the Pulse signal into the gate. I am puzzled as to how this is occurring. Is it possible for such reinjection to happen?

I would greatly appreciate any corrections, recommendations, or insights that could help resolve this issue :)

PS : I do not want a single chip solution. I want to do something to perform the same as a Relay, with no integrated circuits (I want something fast). The Pulse signal is 5v max and is 50ns wide, the load I have chousen randomly (it is for a study I am doing), I should say in the range of 50 ohm (which is commun impedance)

CTL takes either 0 volts or 5 volts

[image]

Comment: What is the voltage range of the CTL signal?

Comment: CTL takes either 0 volts or 5 volts

Answer (score 9):

> I want to do something to perform the same as a Relay [...] I want something fast

CMOS IC switches are **fast**. Blazingly fast. 50ns pulses are no big deal for them. Look for integrated RF switches. There's plenty of them, and they should work just fine in your application. 5V switched voltage range and a 50Ω load are relatively easy conditions for them to work in.

But then, for what you want probably RF reed relays would work very well. They switch in under 1ms. Coto makes excellent ones - even surface mount.

> with no integrated circuits

Integrated circuits will outperform any simple discrete solution by a lot. Sure, you can have a fairly complex discrete solution, but why? Just so that you can be about as good as ICs are?

The circuit you've designed needs negative voltages to fully turn on the PMOS series switches. And PMOS switches have a lot of drain-to-source capacitance, so they'll couple the pulse edges to the load resistors. Then you need to have shorting NMOS switches that bypass the loads.

So, it's rather complificated as they say - although this particular solution works with fairly fast CTL signal. Here, CTL switches at 2MHz and performance is reasonable.

But, at all times the source impedance and the body diode of the PMOS switch is redirecting some of the current from the load to GND through the NMOS switch that's used to "quieten" the load.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fYfalh.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The first part of the circuit is a level shifter for the control voltage. Q1-Q2 are emitter followers. R1-R2 convert control voltage to currents that are then mirrored by the current mirrors Q3-Q4 and Q6-Q7. Q5 is a common base stage that establishes load potential for R2. The GATE control voltage is +/-5V. R6 is an essential load resistor that prevents Q4 and Q7 from saturating.

M1-M6 are inverters that improve the slew rate of the GATE signal. M7-M8 are load switches, and M9-M10 are load shunts that prevent capacitive leakage currents from reaching the loads.

The choices of mosfets are critical and should be tested in the final application, with understanding how their specs affect the performance of the circuit. Generally, you want low-voltage devices with VDS of about 15V, with as low capacitances as possible. Threshold voltages matter as well. M9 and M10 should have as low a threshold as possible.

Unfortunately, mosfets have comparatively egregious capacitances, and a pure-BJT solution would perform better in terms of the load impedance presented at the PULSE source.

Answer (score 0):

The circuit seems overly complex.  At first pass, you can eliminate R15, R16, R21, and R22.  Connect the Q1 base directly to the M7 drain.

If you connect the left side of R10 to the Q1 collector, and decrease R17, you can eliminate M8 and R9.

The circuit can be reduced more, but not without more information.